# ROS hydro build fails on camera_info_manager

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, camera-info-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to build ROS since [iai_kinect2](https://github.com/code-iai/iai_kinect2) needs it. I'm following instructions given [here](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Trusty) and at `catkin_build` command it's failing with the following error:

```
[camera_info_manager] ==> '/home/anshulvj/ros_hydro/build/camera_info_manager/build_env.sh /usr/bin/make --jobserver-fds=3,5 -j' in '/home/anshulvj/ros_hydro/build/camera_info_manager'
[ 50%] Built target camera_info_manager
Linking CXX executable /home/anshulvj/ros_hydro/devel/lib/camera_info_manager/unit_test
/usr/local/lib/libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o): In function `llvm::raw_ostream::raw_ostream(bool)':
gtest-all.cc:(.text._ZN4llvm11raw_ostreamC2Eb[_ZN4llvm11raw_ostreamC5Eb]+0x14): undefined reference to `vtable for llvm::raw_ostream'
/usr/local/lib/libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o): In function `llvm::raw_os_ostream::raw_os_ostream(std::ostream&)':
gtest-all.cc:(.text._ZN4llvm14raw_os_ostreamC2ERSo[_ZN4llvm14raw_os_ostreamC5ERSo]+0x28): undefined reference to `vtable for llvm::raw_os_ostream'
/usr/local/lib/libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o): In function `llvm::convertible_fwd_ostream::~convertible_fwd_ostream()':
gtest-all.cc:(.text._ZN4llvm23convertible_fwd_ostreamD1Ev[_ZN4llvm23convertible_fwd_ostreamD1Ev]+0x44): undefined reference to `llvm::raw_os_ostream::~raw_os_ostream()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/anshulvj/ros_hydro/devel/lib/camera_info_manager/unit_test] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/unit_test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
[camera_info_manager] <== '/home/anshulvj/ros_hydro/build/camera_info_manager/build_env.sh /usr/bin/make --jobserver-fds=3,5 -j' failed with return code '2'
                                                                                                                                                                                     
Starting ==> actionlib                                                                                                                                                              
Failed   <== camera_info_manager              [ 1.4 seconds ]                                                                                                                       
Finished <== image_view                       [ 1.4 seconds ]                                                                                                                       
Starting ==> nodelet_topic_tools                                                                                                                                                    
Finished <== polled_camera                    [ 2.0 seconds ]                                                                                                                       
Finished <== actionlib                        [ 3.1 seconds ]                                                                                                                       
Finished <== nodelet_topic_tools              [ 2.9 seconds ]                                                                                                                       
[build] There were '1' errors:                                                                                                                                                      

Failed to build package 'camera_info_manager' because the following command:

# Command to reproduce:
cd /home/anshulvj/ros_hydro/build/camera_info_manager && /home/anshulvj/ros_hydro/build/camera_info_manager/build_env.sh /usr/bin/make --jobserver-fds=3,5 -j; cd -

# Path to log:
cat /home/anshulvj/ros_hydro/build/build_logs/camera_info_manager.log

Exited with return code: 2 
                                                                                                                                                                                    
[build] Runtime: 2 minutes and 21.2 seconds
```

I tried googling it but noone's apparently gotten this error. I also tried to see if it can be built without the erroneous package but all I found was how to install one single package, not without. Am I missing something obvious. This is the first time I'm installing ROS. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210924/ros-hydro-build-fails-on-camera_info_manager/) by [anshulvj86](https://answers.ros.org/users/22723/anshulvj86/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-06-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-06-10**:
I don't recognize the way you are building it. Does it work in a separate workspace with catkin_make?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-06-10**:
The failure is linking the unit test cases. Do you have the gtest stuff installed? Does it work with `-DCATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING=0`  set?

**Comment by [anshulvj86](https://answers.ros.org/users/22723/anshulvj86/) on 2015-06-10**:
@joq, I'm building it with "catkin build" given at http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Trusty in section 3.1.3. I'm doing it in a separate workspace (I dint initialize it with catkin_make as is given here http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace, since the first link dint say so)

**Comment by [anshulvj86](https://answers.ros.org/users/22723/anshulvj86/) on 2015-06-10**:
@joq. I tried catkin config with `DCATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING=0` but it still gave the same error. I also read about gtest at http://answers.ros.org/question/54075/how-does-rostest-work-with-catkin/ and http://wiki.ros.org/gtest but it says it must be already there (rosdep). Those link don't help me much

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-06-10**:
It should *not* be linking `unit_test` without testing enabled. There must be something seriously wrong with your workspace.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-06-10**:
Note the the CMake variable is named `CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING`. The `-D` prefix is part of the `cmake` command line.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-06-10**:
If you're trying to add a CMake variable to the build (apparently the tutorial uses `catkin build`) here's a quick reference on how to do that: http://catkin-tools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cheat_sheet.html#configuring-workspaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you're trying to follow the [unsupported Hydro/Trusty source installation](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Trusty) instructions in order to use [iai_kinect2](https://github.com/code-iai/iai_kinect2) but `iai_kinect2` is compatible with ROS Indigo, for which there are binary packages on Ubuntu Trusty 14.04.

If you just want to use `iai_kinect2`, then you should follow the ROS Indigo binary installation instructions for Ubuntu Trusty here: http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2015-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anshulvj86](https://answers.ros.org/users/22723/anshulvj86/) on 2015-06-11**:
Thank you all for your replies. I was able to install Indigo on my ubuntu 64 bit 14.04.